# Detecting change in second dropdown (cascading) using HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm having some trouble capturing a change in the second dropdown of a cascading dropdown. Basically my set up is this: the user first picks an ETF from the first dropdown. Upon picking an ETF, a change function detects the selection, sends it to Python using AJAX and populates the second dropdown based on the holdings within the ETF (cascading). This part works perfect. For the second dropdown, I want the user to select a visual and then that selection would be sent to Python as well and then a graph would be produced. I have not gotten to that point yet, but I'm trying to just flash a message letting me know that it is working, but for some reason the second change function does not work.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body> id="body" name="body">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">Welcome to the Alpaca Pair Trading Application! </h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Select ETF</label>
        <select name="etfs" data-live-search="true" id="etfs" class="form-control" class="selectpicker" title="Select ETF">
          {% for etf in etfs %}
          <option value="{{etf}}">{{etf}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Select Visual</label>
        <select name="visuals" data-live-search="true" id="visuals" class="form-control" class="selectpicker" title="Select Visual"> </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
  <p> {{ message }} </p>
  {% endfor %}
  <br>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js">
  </script>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#etfs").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{ url_for('visuals') }}",
      data: {
        etf: $("#etfs").val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var html = "";
        for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
          html += '<option value="' + data[count].id + '">' + data[count].visual + "</option>";
        }
        $("#visuals").html(html);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("change", "$visuals", function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ url_for('graphs') }}",
            data: {
              visual: $("#visuals").val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
              var html = "";
            }
          }
        });
</script>
```

Here is the python code:

```
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    etfs=['DIA','XLV','XLU','XLE','VNQ','GLD/SLV','QQQ','XLP','XLF']
    return render_template("index.html", etfs=etfs)

@app.route("/visuals", methods=["POST","GET"])
def visuals():

    etf_dict={'DIA':['UNH','GS','HD','MSFT','CRM'],'XLP':['PG','KO','PEP','WMT','COST'],
                   'XLV':['JNJ','UNH','PFE','ABT','ABBV'],'XLF':['BRK.B','JPM','BAC','WFC','C'],
                   'XLU':['NEE','DUK','SO','D','EXC'],'VNQ':['AMT','PLD','CCI','EQIX'],
                   'QQQ':['AAPL','MSFT','AMZN','GOOG','FB'],'XLE':['XOM','CVX','COP','MPC','SLB'],
                   'GLD/SLV':['GLD','SLV']}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        etf = request.form['etf']
        holdings=etf_dict[etf]
        options_list=[]

        if etf=='GLD/SLV':
            options_dict={}
            options_dict['id']=etf
            options_dict['visual']='GLD vs SLV'
            options_list.append(options_dict)

        else:
            for i in holdings:
                options_dict={}
                options_dict['id']=etf
                options_dict['visual']=i+' vs '+etf
                options_list.append(options_dict)

            options_list.append({'id':etf,
                         
                         'visual': 'All Holdings vs ' +etf})
        return jsonify(options_list)

@app.route("/graphs", methods=["POST","GET"])
def graphs():
    
    print("inside graphs function")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("received post request from front end")
        graph = request.form['visual']
        flash("This worked! The graph chosen is" + graph)
        return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is what the web app screen looks like. As you can see, when I select "XLE", it updates the second dropdown correctly, so I know the change function is working properly for the first dropdown.

[Web App dropdowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho7VN.png)

The problem is when I select a visual in the second dropdown, the other change function does not seem to be running..

Comment: You simply have a typo: `$(document).on("change", "$visuals", function() {` - should be `#visuals`.  Though as that element exists at page load there is no need to delegate the handler, and a simple `$('#visuals').on('change', function(){...})` will also work.

Comment: Ahh thank you! That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I should be using a form tag to submit the data from each of the dropdowns instead of trying to detect a change in the second dropdown..

Here is the updated HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Alpaca Pair Trading App</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href={{url_for( 'static',filename='css/main.css' )}}>
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <form action='/graphs' method='POST'>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 align="center">Welcome to the Alpaca Pair Trading Application! </h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label>Select ETF</label>
          <select name="etfs" data-live-search="true" id="etfs" class="form-control" class="selectpicker" title="Select ETF">
            {% for etf in etfs %}
            <option value="{{etf}}">{{etf}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label>Select Visual</label>
          <select name="visuals" data-live-search="true" id="visuals" class="form-control" class="selectpicker" title="Select Visual"> </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="submit" name="next" value="Go" class="btn btn-primary">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#etfs").change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ url_for('visuals') }}",
        data: {
          etf: $("#etfs").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {

          var html = "";
          for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
            html += '<option value="' + data[count].visual + '">' + data[count].visual + "</option>";
          }

          $("#visuals").html(html);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```